# Reading a big chunk of data from Unix SOCK_STREAM socket

Tags: sockets, unix, asyncsocket

I am new to asynchronous I/O. 
I need to read a big chuck of data from Unix SOCK_STREAM socket.I am using non-blocking socket.
It may require more than one read/recv(). That part is fine with me.

My doubt is --
If at a time 3-4 clients are writing huge data to my server socket say each one is writing 100K data. 
Is it can be a scenario where my first read is reading some data(say 40 K) from client1 and second read is reading data from client 2 and third read is again reading remaining data from client1?

Regards
DJ

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question very much depend on how you define client1 to clientN. Specifically, how do they form the connection to the server.

A SOCK_STREAM is connection oriented. This means that your server creates a listening socket, binds to it and then when the client connects the server accepts the connection and gets in essence a new socket.

Now, if client1 to clientN will each do a seperate connection the server will basically have N different sockets, In this case, the answer to your questions is no - data from the different clients will not mix since they are being transmitted on different sockets.

However, if you have the sort of arrangement where you have a father-client that opens the connection and that socket is shared by clients1 to n (say in different threads or child processes) then the answer is yes - the writes on a specific socket are not atomic and the data can mix.

As a side note, if you use a Unix pipe rather then a unix domain socket, you will get the benefit of writes being atomic even with different writers on the same pipe uo to a certain threshold (at least 512 according to POSIX, Linux actually supports 65000 bytes)

Comment: In that case the operations will be atomic between the different clients since each is operating on a different socket. So the answer to your question is: no, the data will not mix. These are different sockets.

Comment: my server is using epoll for polling of clients. And all clients will have their own different connection i.e your case 1. Client open a connection during it s own startup and connection will remain open thorough out. After that client will keep on sending a big chucks of data. Now my Question is -- If say 3 clients have written 100 KBytes data to my server and suppose my server is reading 50K at a time. So I will get total  6 read trigger from epoll. Now my doubt is, will get trigger in proper sequence like trigger 1 & 2 for client 1, trigger 3 & 4 for client 2, trigger 5 & 6 for client 3.

Comment: No, you cannot count of the triggers to come in any specific order between different sockets/clients, only with regard to each socket in itself.  

That is: the second trigger for client1 will always come after the first but there is no guaranteeing the order it will get with regard to the triggers for client2

Comment: so, answer to my Question " Is it can be a scenario where my first read is reading some data(say 40 K) from client1 and second read is reading data from client 2 and third read is again reading remaining data from client1?" Is YES. Am I right? So, handling such kind of scenario, I have to keep some kind of mapping between between Client and data until i am not done with reading whole data from a specific client.